# Fable F# > js compile multiple .fsx files

Tags: f#, fable-f#

How can I compile multiple `.fsx` files using Fable?

I (naively) tried to just pass an array of them in the fable.config file like this:

```
{
    "outDir": "app",
    "projFile":["app/index.fsx", "app/testmod.fsx"],
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "targets": {
        "production": {
            "sourceMaps": false
        }
    }
}
```

but get the warning:

```
ARG ERROR: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received [ 'app/index.fsx', 'app/testmod.fsx' ]
```

I know I could make a full-blown .fsproj file and point the fable compiler to that but it seems like overkill to do this simply in order to add-in a reference.

It feels like I am missing something really simple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I really was missing something simple!

The really really straightforward solution is just to use a reference in the `.fsx` file itself and don't worry about pointing Fable at the referenced file.

**index.fsx:**

```
module App

#load "testmod.fsx" //this reference is all thats needed!
```

Then we need no reference inside the
**fable.config:**

```
{
    "outDir": "app",
    "projFile":"app/index.fsx",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "targets": {
        "production": {
            "sourceMaps": false
        }
    }
}
```

<sub><sup>Note to self - try the simplest solution first before posting on Stack Overflow!</sup></sub>