# How to open Modules from other files in Fable-F#

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'm brand new to Fable and I'm having some issues opening a custom module from a different file.

Here's my basic file setup

```
node_modules
 |
public
 |
src 
 |_ App.fsx
 |_ OtherFile.fsx
```

Inside the App.fsx file:

```
open CustomModule
```

Inside the OtherFile.fsx file

```
module CustomModule =

    let greeting = 
        printfn "hello from CustomModule"
```

Here is my fableconfig.json file:

```
{
    "projFile": "./src/App.fsx", 
    "outDir": "./public",
    "scripts": {
        "postbuild": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack"
    }
```

}

Whenever I try to reference CustomModule, I get a `The namespace or module 'CustomModule' is not defined.` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Fable has changed a lot recently. I'm not sure if `fableconfig.json` is still a thing. I see no mention of it [here](http://fable.io/docs/getting-started.html). What version are you on? Are you following a particular guide? It may be out of date.

Comment: And have you tried doing `open OtherFile.CustomModule`? Usually when you define a single top-level module in a whole file you don't put the `=` after it, and you don't need to indent what comes below. That may fix your problem without changing the `open` statement.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox  I've been using this [guide](http://inchingforward.com/2017/03/getting-started-with-fable-elmish/) which was created 6 months ago. Is there a better resource I should be using? I did try removing the "=" symbol and the extra indentation, but no dice.

Comment: Use the getting started guide on the official website that I linked in my first comment. There are also [more templates listed here](https://github.com/kunjee17/awesome-fable#templates).

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Thanks for the link! I'll definitely check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39852857/8364675), whose answer solved my issue.

Just call the following to load other modules

```
#load "OtherFile.fsx"
```